# make acute angle triangle with cube

Tags: algorithm

Think of the 8 vertices of a given cube. You are allowed to join three
vertices to form a triangle. How many such unique acute triangles can you
make ??

Someone asked me this question and i gave him 8 as the answer..can someone make it more clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get an acute triangle this way is to connect the diagonals of three adjacent faces. You can select 3 adjacent faces of a cube in (6*4*2)/(3*2*1) = 8 different ways.

Comment: I think youre right, I forgot this possibility.